# Cloud DNS, 1 of 2 subdomains not resolving

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dns

```
mysite.com.     NS  21600   ns-cloud-c1.googledomains.com.
ns-cloud-c2.googledomains.com.
ns-cloud-c3.googledomains.com.
ns-cloud-c4.googledomains.com.

mysite.com.     SOA     21600   ns-cloud-c1.googledomains.com. cloud-dns-hostmaster.google.com. 1 21600 3600 259200 300


api.mysite.com.     A   300     34.xx.xxx.xx


client.mysite.com.  CNAME   60  c.storage.googleapis.com.
```

Above is the setup for my domain. I can get to the frontend (VUE app) at client.mysite.com by typing the url into any browser. The backend, however, will not resolve. I can reach the backend api using the ip address, but when I use the sub/domain name it says server not found. What gives? Am I misunderstanding something? I've read and reread through Google's docs and can not seem to figure this one out.

Comment: Use an Internet tool such as MxToolbox to test and debug your DNS records.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, though I'm not sure how that helps. As one would expect, it says 'DNS record not found' when entering in the api subdomain.

Comment: Since you are masking your DNS records, how can we help you? I can point you to tools that will tell what is wrong. You will need to figure out what the solution is from those error messages. Otherwise, you will need to post the actual DNS names records for us to review. In one of your records, you mention storage. If that record has a problem you will also need to show the storage configuration. there is no magic here, the answer is in the details. You have not provided details.

Comment: I just noticed you do not have a resource record for the naked domain (mysite.com) which in most cases is an "A" record.

Comment: Got some insight from a colleague and it appears (or at least I hope) this may have something to do with the registrar setup. The domain is registered through Google, but managed through domains.google.com (which I don't have access to). I only have access to CloudDNS through GCP console. Two separate things apparently, and may be the reason behind all this...

Answer (score 0):

The domain registrar (domains.google.com) was not configured properly. Once changed to direct to the name servers listed in GCP (shown in question), the domain is resolving. However, the change did take a notable amount of time before it worked.